# Clone/relay exact request to another URL (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to clone/relay the exact request to another URL in native NodeJs. For example, if you send a POST request to my site "example.com", it will send the exact same request you sent to another URL "example2.com" (data, headers etc). How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use proxy middleware to duplicate the request. For example [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware) will allow you to proxy the request to another server, but from what I can tell, you can only modify the response. Which isn't optimal if you don't want to wait on the proxy. You might just grab the main [proxy library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware#recipes) itself, something like:

```
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const proxyMiddleware = httpProxy.createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'http://www.example2.com',
    selfHandleResponse: true
});

const customProxyMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    proxy.web(req, res);
    next();
};

// This passes all incoming requests to the proxy but does not handle
// any of them. It simply passes it along.
app.use('/', customProxyMiddleware);
```

This code may not work exactly as intended but it should be a good starting point for what you are attempting.